# Ordernar consulta (1,2,3,1,2,3.1......)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, select

Que tal tengo una tabla **alumnos** con una columna llamada "**id_escuelas**"
en Mysql
[image: estructura de la tabla] Lo quiero es al realizar un "select" que me arroje los resultados ordenados de la siguiente manera:

```
nombre_a         id_escuelas 
---------       -------------
  Juan               1 
  Roman              2
  Raul               3
  Omar               1
  Jose               2
```

Encontre en el siguiente enlace (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959414/mysql-how-do-i-order-results-by-alternating-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-rows-i)
un pedazo de codigo que lo adapte a mi tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT x.id_escuelas,
       x.nombre_a
FROM (SELECT alumnos.id_escuelas,
             alumnos.nombre_a,
             CASE
                WHEN @id_escuelas != alumnos.id_escuelas THEN @rownum := 0
                WHEN @id_escuelas = alumnos.id_escuelas THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                ELSE @rownum
              END AS rank,
              @id_escuelas := alumnos.id_escuelas
         FROM TABLE alumnos,
              (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id_escuelas
      ORDER BY alumnos.id_escuelas) r) x
ORDER BY x.rank, x.id_escuelas
```

Pero me arroja errores:
[image: error]

Si elimino la palabra table:
[image: error 2]

De antemano Gracias

Comment: Estoy siguiendo todo el codigo, y tengo miedo que al ser una respuesta tan vieja (2009!) algo haya cambiado en el medio y por eso no funcione...

Answer (score 2):

Con algunos ajustes, la consulta funciona:

```sql
SELECT
  /*x.id_escuelas,
  x.nombre_a*/
  `x`.`nombre_a`,
  `x`.`id_escuelas`
FROM (
  SELECT
    `alumnos`.`id_escuelas`,
    `alumnos`.`nombre_a`,
    CASE
      WHEN @`id_escuelas` != `alumnos`.`id_escuelas`
        THEN @`rownum` := 0
      WHEN @`id_escuelas` = `alumnos`.`id_escuelas`
        THEN @`rownum` := @`rownum` + 1
      ELSE @`rownum`
    END AS `rank`,
    @`id_escuelas` := `alumnos`.`id_escuelas`
  -- FROM TABLE
  FROM
    `alumnos`,
    /*(SELECT @rownum := 0, @id_escuelas
    ORDER BY alumnos.id_escuelas) r) x*/
    (SELECT @`rownum` := 0, @`id_escuelas` := 0) `r`
  ORDER BY `alumnos`.`id_escuelas`
) `x`
ORDER BY `x`.`rank`, `x`.`id_escuelas`;
```

Ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6mnT3ciYexshrJ8TCP8u1R/0).

No estoy seguro la versión de MySQL usada por usted. El ejemplo se elaboró sobre MySQL 5.7.17.

En caso de usar MySQL 8.0.x, tenga presente que desde la versión 8.0.2 `RANK` es una palabra reservada ([9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words :: R](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R)). Usando MySQL 8.0.x podrá usar las [12.20 Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), es decir, algo como:

```sql
SELECT
  `x`.`nombre_a`,
  `x`.`id_escuelas`
FROM (
  SELECT
    `alumnos`.`id_escuelas`,
    `alumnos`.`nombre_a`,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `alumnos`.`id_escuelas`) AS `rank`
  FROM
    `alumnos`
) `x`
ORDER BY `x`.`rank`, `x`.`id_escuelas`;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0bbd4dbaf0657bbf0853467e4839283).

Comment: Le agradezco mucho la ayuda!, y en efecto uso la version 5.7.17, pero es de mucha utilidad conocer el otro ejemplo con la version 8.0.2
Saludos!